# React.cloneElement() giving cannot read props of undefined error unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am passing some JSX through a React component prop. I am then trying to clone that JSX in order to add a listener, using React.cloneElement(). Doing so however give me the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Here is the component that is passing the JSX into a child React element:

```
<FormModal
    size='small'
    formName='sortForm'
    header='Sort'
    headerIcon='sort'
    handleSubmit={ this.sortSubmit }
    content={
        <SortForm table={ this.props.table } initialValues={ { orderBy: this.props.search.orderBy, orderDirection: this.props.search.orderDirection } } />
    }
    trigger={
        <Button icon floated='right' size="mini">
            <Icon name='sort' />
        </Button>
    }
/>
```

Here is the `FormModal` code that clones the passed in `content` and `trigger` props:

```
class FormModal extends Component {

    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.handleOkay = this.handleOkay.bind( this );
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind( this );
        this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind( this );
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind( this );
        this.modalOpen = false;
        // here:
        this.content = React.cloneElement(
            this.props.content, 
            { onSubmit: this.handleSubmit }
        );
        this.trigger = React.cloneElement(
            this.props.trigger, 
            { onClick: this.handleOpen }
        );
    }
```

If I replace `this.props.content` and `this.props.trigger` in the `cloneElement()` arguments with some simple JSX like `<div></div>`, it works without error, so I know the issue is with those props being passed in. I cannot figure out why however. console logging those props just beforehand shows they are not undefined.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle replicating the error by any chance?

Comment: @Anuj I do not understand how to set up my React environment in jsfiddle unfortunately. I try using their base react fiddle and I just start getting errors setting up a couple simple objects and I don't know why.

https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Comment: try https://codesandbox.io/ - it seems to be a bit easier to use with React!

Comment: @Anuj got it. here it is. the error doesn't seem to occur until the JSX being passed in uses the `this` keyword on the outer object. https://codesandbox.io/s/L94OZO0QD

Comment: Although we have the same error, it's being generated for a different reason here. Stateless components don't have access to `this.props` so we have to write the function in a different way: https://codesandbox.io/s/P1krwYG8n - Are you able to recreate your error using a stateful component and the `cloneElement` method?

Comment: @Anuj I caught that after I left the previous comment. Nope. Once I changed it into a class, I lost the error. I re-saved it. I cannot for the life of me see what's different between the codesandbox and the above code. Why one is erroring and the other is not.

Comment: Can you add in the cloneElement and binding in the constructor into your codesandbox? It might help us replicate and diagnose the issue

Comment: @Anuj the cloning is in there, inside of Hello. I added the binding of the method as well. It didn't seem to change.

Comment: @Anuj another clue, commenting out the second clone stops the error. so the content clone is working fine, but the trigger clone is breaking.

Comment: @Anuj gah I figured it out. it was a whole separate instance of the same Element that was missing a prop. sorry for wasting your time. thank you for the help! and also pointing me to codesandbox